# How to merge multiple rows into one row with SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Originally, I have one table, storing UserID and the corresponding value based on Year, Month, as shown below:

[image: Original Table]

Now, I want to 'merge' the rows according to the Year and Month value and to store them into another table, as shown below:

[image]

Note that, M1 means Mth = 1 (January), M2 means Mth = 2 (February), and so on. (The images are meant for description, you may ignore the accuracy of the figure.)

Question, how to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic case of a pivot operation in SQL. The method working in, probably, most (if not all) SQL products, including SQL Server, is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  UserID,
  Year,
  M1  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  1 THEN Value END),
  M2  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  2 THEN Value END),
  M3  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  3 THEN Value END),
  M4  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  4 THEN Value END),
  M5  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  5 THEN Value END),
  M6  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  6 THEN Value END),
  M7  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  7 THEN Value END),
  M8  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  8 THEN Value END),
  M9  = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN  9 THEN Value END),
  M10 = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN 10 THEN Value END),
  M11 = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN 11 THEN Value END),
  M12 = SUM(CASE Mth WHEN 12 THEN Value END)
FROM
  dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY
  UserID,
  Year
;
```

SQL Server also supports the [PIVOT operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (since the 2005 version). I can see two distinct approaches using PIVOT here. One is probably more straightforward:

```
SELECT
  UserID,
  Year,
  M1  =  [1],
  M2  =  [2],
  M3  =  [3],
  M4  =  [4],
  M5  =  [5],
  M6  =  [6],
  M7  =  [7],
  M8  =  [8],
  M9  =  [9],
  M10 = [10],
  M11 = [11],
  M12 = [12]
FROM
  dbo.YourTable
PIVOT
  (
    SUM(Value)
    FOR Mth IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
  ) AS p
;
```

Note that the above method assumes your table has no other columns apart from those shown in your example (*UserID*, *Year*, *Mth*, *Value*). If there are other columns, replace *dbo.YourTable* with a derived table pulling only those four columns:

```
  ...
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      UserID,
      Year,
      Mth,
      Value
    FROM
      dbo.YourTable
  ) AS s
PIVOT
  ...
```

The other, slightly less obvious, option would be to use a derived table to construct the final `Mn` columns and thus avoid the renaming in the main SELECT:

```
SELECT
  UserID,
  Year,
  M1,
  M2,
  M3,
  M4,
  M5,
  M6,
  M7,
  M8,
  M9,
  M10,
  M11,
  M12
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      UserID,
      Year,
      Mth = 'M' + CAST(Mth AS varchar(11)),
      Value
    FROM
      dbo.YourTable
  ) AS s
PIVOT
  (
    SUM(Value)
    FOR Mth IN (M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12)
  )
  UserID,
  Year
;
```

In this case you could also use just `*` in the main SELECT instead of the explicit column list.