# Converting multiple rows to one row

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data coming from Finger Print devices, Each In and Out of employees are recorded.

```
UserId         CheckTime              CheckType
------        -----------            -----------
  2      2020-08-03 08:15:12.053          I
  2      2020-08-03 16:00:00.053          O
  2      2020-08-04 08:00:12.053          I
  2      2020-08-04 16:10:00.053          O
```

I want the above data to be as following:

```
UserId         CheckTime           CommingTime                 LeavingTime
------        -----------          -----------                -------------
  2           2020-08-03           08:15:12.053               16:00:00.053
  2           2020-08-04           08:00:12.053               16:10:00.053
```

**Note: ** *A user can have multiple In Out record per day*

I have tried the following answers but didn't help:

[How to merge multiple rows into one row with SQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140683/how-to-merge-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-sql)

*Any idea??*

Comment: is it possible that you may have no corresponding Out records for some In records and vice versa? what version of database server do you use?

Comment: And what happens when someone comes in before midnight but leaves after midnight?

Comment: How is this (ignoring the noted complications) not simply the minimum of the "in" rows and the maximum of the "out" rows with the appropriate group by clause?

Comment: @SMor: Seems to me like a valid option to suggest. Keep in mind that comments can't bring you rep points, but *answers* can (wink, wink, nudge, nudge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main idea:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT UserId, 
                     CheckTime, 
                     LEAD(CheckTime) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY CheckTime) NextTime, 
                     CheckType, 
                     LEAD(CheckType) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY CheckTime) NextType )
SELECT UserId, CheckTime, NextTime
FROM cte
WHERE CheckType = 'I'
  AND NextType = 'O'
```

Modify as you need - extract date and/or time parts, check that date parts are equal, etc.